# Windows MGET Switches to limit files by date

Tags: cmd, ftp

does the MGET command have any switches to limit the files selected by date/most recent etc?

eg. I am using FTP in a cmd/bat file to download csv files as follows:

```
mget "*.csv"
```

Is there any way of only retrieving files dated today or later, eg:

```
mget "*.csv >=1D"
```

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1):

No. The MGET command only accepts filenames or wildcards (filter by name).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490668.aspx

FTP command line is a simple application. 
However, using FTP commands you can take the output of the FTP directory and filter (using some scripting language or a batch file) the file names using the output, but it could be difficult.

You can try other tools like **`wget`** that comes with several options to "mirror" or syncing folders using the file time (local and remote).

See some examples: http://www.labnol.org/software/wget-command-examples/28750/